# Deducing phase from frequency response $1-z^{-1} $

Tags: phase, z-transform, frequency-response

In Boaz Porat's book about signal proccessing, at part 8 he mentions the example:
$$ H\left(z\right)=1-z^{-1}\Rightarrow H^{f}\left(\theta\right)=1-e^{-j\theta}=\left(e^{\frac{j\theta}{2}}-e^{-\frac{j\theta}{2}}\right)e^{-\frac{j\theta}{2}}= \\
2j\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{-\frac{j\theta}{2}}=2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{j\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)} $$
Therefore the amplitude and phase are given by:
$$ \left|H^{f}\left(\theta\right)\right|=\left|2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|$$
$$\psi\left(\theta\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2} & 0<\theta<\pi\\
-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2} & -\pi<\theta<0
\end{cases} $$
How did he find the phase and why would it not be the same for all $-\pi <\theta <\pi $?

Also, how would the phase look if instead of $\sin $ he would represent it with a $\cos $? would the regions be $$ \begin{cases}
-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2} & \frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\pi\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2} & -\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}\\
-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2} & -\pi<\theta<-\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases} $$

In general, how do I find the frequency response given a transfer function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you want to express $x$ as modulus and phase. This is: $x = |x|$ if $x \ge 0$, and $x = -|x|$ when $x < 0$.
That minus sign is equivalent to a phase of $\pi$; remember that $-1 = e^{j\pi}$.

For your example above, when $\sin(\cdots)$ is negative, then you have to add (or subtract) a phase of $\pi$, which is why you have 2 expressions for the phase depending on the frequency $\theta$. And there is an extra $\pi/2$ phase that comes from the $j$ multiplying the sine.

For your other question, the difference of exponentials gives a sine, not a cosine. So it is not straightforward how to represent the frequency response if terms of cosines.

Comment: For your last comment, couldn't we use $sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta - \pi/2)$ ?